# Render Livecharts Chart in Memory and Save as Image

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, livecharts

I'm trying to do the following:

- Create a Livechart Cartesian chart in memory
- Add the chart to a grid
- Add Labels to the same grid
- Add the grid to a Viewbox
- Render the Viewbox as a PNG
- Save the PNG to disk

The above should be run from a different thread in the background in order to allow UI reponsiveness.

However simple this may seem, I've been struggling to get a proper working solution.  The following issues are relevant:

- The Livechart (which is inside the Viewbox) takes time to render
- Thus the chart needs to be given time to complete rendering before trying to save it as an image
- I have found code which makes use of HwndSource, however it is not working all the time (works about 95% of the time).  Without the HwndSource modification it NEVER works (always gets a chart with nothing on it)
- Running the Run() function in a different UI thread does not work,  as I get the following error message: WPF Dispatcher {“The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.”}

So my questions are:

- What is the right way to wait for the Livechart/Grid/ViewBox combination to finish rendering before saving it as an image?  Maybe make use of the Loaded event?  Note that I have tried to impelment it but cannot get it to work as I hit the 'threading' issue.
- How can I run the entire process in a different UI thread?

See below for code

```
public void Run()
(
   //Create Livechart which is a child of a Grid control
   Grid gridChart = Charts.CreateChart();
   //Creates a ViewBox control which has the grid as its child
   Viewbox viewBox = WrapChart(gridChart,1400,700);
   //Creates and saves the image
   CreateAndSaveImage(viewBox ,path,name);
)
```

Below is the function which creates the Viewbox and add the grid as a child

```
public Viewbox viewBox WrapChart(Grid grid,int width,int height)
{

    chart.grid.Width = width;
    chart.grid.Height = height;

    viewbox.Child = chart.grid;

    viewbox.Width = width;
    viewbox.Height = height;
    viewbox.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(width, height));
    viewbox.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
    viewbox.UpdateLayout();

}
```

Function below creates and saves the image

```
public void CreateAndSaveImage(Viewbox viewbox,string folderPath,string fileName)
{
    var x = HelperFunctions.GetImage(viewbox);
    System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create(folderPath + fileName);
    HelperFunctions.SaveAsPng(x, stream);
    stream.Close();   
}
```

The following code renders the viewbox to an image.  Note that this is the only code that I could find which waits for the chart to finish loading.  I have no idea how it works, but it works 95% of the time.  Sometimes a chart still does not finish loading.

```
public static RenderTargetBitmap GetImage(Viewbox view)
{

      using (new HwndSource(new HwndSourceParameters())
      {
          RootVisual =
                           (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(view) == null
                                ? view
                                : null)
      })
      {

          Size size = new Size(view.ActualWidth, view.ActualHeight);
          if (size.IsEmpty)
              return null;


          int actualWidth = Convert.ToInt32(size.Width);
          int requiredWidth = Convert.ToInt32(size.Width * 1);

          int actualHeight = Convert.ToInt32(size.Height);
          int requiredHeight = Convert.ToInt32(size.Height * 1);

          // Flush the dispatcher queue
          view.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(() => { }));

          var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(requiredWidth, requiredHeight,
                                                          96d * requiredWidth / actualWidth, 96d * requiredHeight / actualHeight,
                                                          PixelFormats.Pbgra32);


          DrawingVisual drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();
          using (DrawingContext context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
          {
              context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(view), null, new Rect(new Point(), size));
              context.Close();
          }

          renderBitmap.Render(view);
          renderBitmap.Freeze();

          return renderBitmap;
      }


}
```

The following code saves the bitmap as a picture to file

```
public static void SaveAsPng(BitmapSource src, Stream outputStream)
{
      PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
      encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));

      encoder.Save(outputStream);
}
```

The following code is what I use to run the entire thing in a different thread.  Note that it is not working, as I get the following error message:

> WPF Dispatcher {“The calling thread cannot access this object because
>   a different thread owns it.”}.

Note that if I execute Run() normally (without any separate threads) it works, however sometimes the chart does not render properly (as explained previously).

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
       Run();

       System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();

});

       thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
       thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try call this line for the chart:

```
    this.chart.Model.Updater.Run(false, true);
```

This line updates the chart and always is visible when save to image.

Comment: Thanks man, had to use a massive workaround to make it work.  So simple